# How to pause long enough that cmd.exe exits?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, cmd, tortoisegit

I am updating TortoiseGit repository using the following code (which works) in command line file (MyTestRepo.cmd):

```
cd c:\MyTortoiseGitRepo
git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase "origin"
```

In PowerShell I am calling this file using the following code:

```
$TestPull = Start-Job { Invoke-Item C:\MyTests\MyTestRepo.cmd }
Wait-Job $TestPull
Receive-Job $TestPull
```

The above code does work but it is not waiting long enough for the CMD file to finish running and exit cmd.exe to exit before moving on to the next line of code.

What better way to you have to wait for the cmd.exe process to finish before moving on?

Comment: Don't use `Start-Job`. Just type `C:\MyTests\MyTestRepo.cmd` and hit `Enter`. PowerShell will run the script and wait for it to complete.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I would still recommend using the call operator just in case the path includes a space and needs to be quoted++ There's probably a reason he's using a job, ex. to run something else between starting the cmd and waiting for it.

Comment: have you tried -Wait inside of the Start-Job?

Comment: @KahnKah There's no `-Wait` switch for `Invoke-Item`.

Comment: Frode F. is correct, the `&` operator is needed if the command contains spaces. The larger question is why `Start-Job` is needed in the first place. Just run the command.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart  The Start-Job command is required as the TortoiseGIT pull command only works directly in a cmd window. I tried many different methods which all fail when not running the command directly in a cmd window.  As noted below I commented on error through when using & too.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invoke-Item` doesn't support waiting. You can use the call operator `&`. Ex:

```
$TestPull = Start-Job { & "C:\MyTests\MyTestRepo.cmd" }
```

Or `Start-Process -Wait`:

```
$TestPull = Start-Job { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\MyTests\MyTestRepo.cmd" -Wait }
```

`Start-Process` will show the cmd-window when the script is excecuted by a user. This can be suppressed by adding `-`NoNewWindow`.

Comment: I'd prefer the call operator (`&`).

Comment: I agree, but couldn't remember if it waited. Updated answer +1

Comment: The window can be suppressed by adding the `-NoNewWindow` switch.

Comment: Using the first command causing the cmd file to be run directly in PowerShell "$TestPull = Start-Job { & "C:\MyTests\MyTestRepo.cmd" }." However, the second command runs like a champ in that it is running the cmd file externally in the command window "$TestPull = Start-Job { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\MyTests\MyTestRepo.cmd" -Wait }"  Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: the -NoNewWindow option does cause an error with processing the data from the background process.  Just to let you know.